# Dynamic Left Navigation bar

Tags: jquery, navigation

I need to showcase dynamically newly added list items in the left navigation bar. I have a master list.
Please tell me the solution using jquery or server object model

In sharepoint 2013, site definition, 
I have a req. that whenever user add items in list,it should dynamically be added in the left navigation bar under the list name

Comment: This question needs more information. Give us as much as you can regarding your scenario, target, and environment (like SP version etc.)

Comment: the question has been updated...please find the same

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be injected into the left hand navigation? I'm not sure how to specifically do that, but here are 3 alternatives that I use frequently to accomplish the same business need and display the results on a page.

(1) Content Query Web Part (within one site collection), and point it at the target list

(2) Content Search Web Part (crossing site collections), and point it at the target list

(3) Another option otherwise is to use a Snippet web part and print the values on the screen using a real-time ajax request

```
$.ajax({
   url : <REST/OData endpoint here pointing at your list>,
   headers : "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose",
   success : function onSuccess(data, request){
      // iterate returned values and print latest values here
   },
   error : function onError(error) {
      // Error handling 
   }
});
```